# Using CSS Counter values as ids for corresponding element id attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pretty sure I have to use javascript for this, but double checking anyways.

Wondering if anyone has figured out a no script way to use CSS counters as the id property value for elements without using javascript?  Or if javascript is necessary is it possible to grab the counter value without recreating the counter?

For example I've created this [component test page](https://superflycss.github.io/component-test/target/test/html/).  You'll notice that each When / Then test has a css counter generated number.  I want to use that counter value as the id attribute value of the corresponding element.  That way links to tests can be sent like this:

```
 https://superflycss.github.io/component-test/target/test/html/#2
```

That would scroll to the second test when entered in the browser.

I add some compile time scripting to [superflycss/cli](https://github.com/superflycss/cli) to enable this, but wanted to make sure there's no dead simple option first.

Comment: This is what [HTML5 spec says](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#an-indicated-part-of-the-document). I dont think that css has access to location.href.

Comment: According to [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#counters) counter can be used only in `content` property.